# jquery slideUp/ slideDown xui equivalent

Tags: javascript, animation, mobile-website, xui

Hello im trying to create the same effect of jQuery's slideUp and slideDown function with [xui]http://xuijs.com)

so far i have created the fade effect

```
xui.extend({
           fadeOut:function(dur, callback) {       
           this.tween({opacity:'0',duration:dur}, callback);
       },

           fadeIn:function(dur, callback) {       
           this.tween({opacity:'1',duration:dur}, callback);
       }
});
```

which has been successful:)

But I am trying to master the slideUp/Down but have no luck.
I have tried:

```
   slideUp:function(dur, callback) {       
       this.tween({height:'0',duration:dur}, callback);
   }
```

which works on elements without padding and a border. Is there anybody who can help me solve this problem any advice will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Not sure if you use GIT but it would be nice to try to add them to https://github.com/xui/xui-plugins/blob/master/jquery-compat/jquery-compat.js I just made a push request for NEXT and IS functions @ https://github.com/JKirchartz/xui-plugins/blob/master/jquery-compat/jquery-compat.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a fadeOut on the padding & border, or set them to auto or none...